# D3.js / NVD3.js does not display correct values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I'm new to D3.js and NVD3.js. I created a multi-line chart for displaying statistics. The displayed numbers on y-axis and inside the chart are integers only.

However it does not display the correct values from the dataset. The JSON input looks like this:

```
[{"key":"Anmeldungen","values":[[1446505200,92],[1447023600,112],[1447542000,361],[1448665200,6],[1449183600,10],[1449788400,2],[1449961200,3],[1450738800,4],[1451343600,9],[1451689200,2],[1452294000,7],[1452380400,5],[1453330800,7],[1453849200,2],[1454540400,4],[1454799600,7]]},{"key":"Abmeldungen ","values":[[1446505200,223],[1447023600,264],[1447542000,82],[1448665200,0],[1449183600,0],[1449788400,0],[1449961200,0],[1450738800,0],[1451343600,0],[1451689200,0],[1452294000,0],[1452380400,0],[1453330800,2],[1453849200,0],[1454540400,0],[1454799600,0]]}]
```

The first number of the value is a timestamp, that is **displayed correctly** in the chart. The second number is the integer value I'm having trouble with.

The code for rendering the chart is the following:

```
var $json = JSON.parse($json);
nv.addGraph(function () {
    data = $json;
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
            .x(function (d) {
                return d[0]*1000 //timestamp
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                console.log(d); //<--Outputs correct number
                return d[1]
            })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        ;

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%d.%m.%Y')(new Date(d))
        });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    console.log(data); // <-- still has the correct data

    d3.select('.diagrammContainer svg').datum(data).call(chart);

    return chart;
});
```

I also tried to change

```
chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
```

to

```
chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
```

which displayed floating numbers on the y-axis. But the values are still incorrect. I also do not understand why it converts a few numbers to negatives.

The both console.log´s in the code output the correct values. What does D3.js / NVD3.js do with the numbers that the chart looks like this? 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cCoS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying to debug this for a little while, I did some googling. These were my two findings:

- The values of the data you create the chart from should be objects rather than arrays, so instead of `{"key":"Anmeldungen","values":[[1446505200,92],...`, you want `..."values":[{ x: 1446505200, y: 92},...`. In changing this, you also need to change `.x()` and `.y()` functions to return `d.x*1000` and `d.y`, respectively.
- Evidently the mishandling of y-values by the nvd3 cumulative line chart [is a known issue](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/695), but if you change it to a lineChart instead(i.e. `var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()` to `var chart = nv.models.lineChart()`), it will resolve the y-values correctly.

I took the liberty of creating a snippet demonstrating how it works with the data value arrays replaced with `{x:_, y:_}` objects, and [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yud0wzmL/) I modified from the one in the github issues thread with your data, if you'd like to play around with it.

```js
var data = [{"key":"AN","values":[[1446505200,92],[1447023600,112],[1447542000,361],[1448665200,6],[1449183600,10],[1449788400,2],[1449961200,3],[1450738800,4],[1451343600,9],[1451689200,2],[1452294000,7],[1452380400,5],[1453330800,7],[1453849200,2],[1454540400,4],[1454799600,7]]},{"key":"AB ","values":[[1446505200,223],[1447023600,264],[1447542000,82],[1448665200,0],[1449183600,0],[1449788400,0],[1449961200,0],[1450738800,0],[1451343600,0],[1451689200,0],[1452294000,0],[1452380400,0],[1453330800,2],[1453849200,0],[1454540400,0],[1454799600,0]]}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < data[i].values.length; j++) {
   data[i].values[j] = {
     x: data[i].values[j][0], 
      y: data[i].values[j][1]
    };
  }
}

console.log(data);

window.nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .x(function(d) {return d.x*1000})
                .y(function(d) {return d.y}) 
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    .width($('#cumulative-test').width())
    .height($('#cumulative-test').height())
       .color(d3.scale.category10().range());
 
    chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
     return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    });
    
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
 
    d3.select("#cumulative-test svg").datum(getData()).call(chart);
 
    nv.utils.windowResize(updateChart);
      
    function updateChart() {
     chart.width($("#cumulative-test svg").width())
     chart.height($("#cumulative-test svg").height());
     chart.update();
    }
 
    return chart;  
    
    function getData() {
        return data;
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.css" />
<div id="cumulative-test" style="width:100%; height:50%;">
 <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Changing the "cumulativeLineChart" to "lineChart" finally solved the issue. I also changed the "values" array so it contains objects rather than arrays. Thank you for this hint.